# Firebase navbar login

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

here is a problem with my navigation bar, when I get my website, I sometimes see this soon:

[image]

I'm using `ng-show` and `ng-hide`, for when you are logged in or not.

Is this the best way or is there a better way?

Sincerely,

Jur Dekker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `ng-cloak` to prevent from being briefly displayed by the browser.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak